# Code not working: Using Javascript to dynamically add items to a list in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, append

EDIT: JSFiddle indicates the code itself is good. Can anyone give some insight into why it may not be executing properly as a chrome extension?

I'm trying to make a simple To-do list Chrome extension for myself. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

    <title>To-Do-List</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div id="header"><h3 id="headtext">TO DO LIST</h3></div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="textbox" placeholder="Input"></input>
            </form>
            <button id="add">Add</button>

                <p>TO DO LIST:</p>
                    <ul id="myList">
                    </ul>

        </body>
    </html>
```

And the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("textbox").value);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
    }
    )
</script>
```

When I enter text in the input field then click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: what it says, any console error, working for me http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/L6q58tf9/20/

Comment: Test in below JSFiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/4Lqyqker/

Comment: The JSFiddle above shows that it is working correctly.

Comment: It works in those JSFiddle examples because by default JSFiddle wraps your JS code in a window onload handler (as specified in the drop-down under the Frameworks & Extensions heading). Your actual code doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit by adding window.onload function.

See below. it works now.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

    <title>To-Do-List</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
var node = document.createElement("li");
var textnode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("textbox").value);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}
) 

};



</script>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div id="header"><h3 id="headtext">TO DO LIST</h3></div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="textbox" placeholder="Input"></input>
            </form>
            <button id="add">Add</button>

                <p>TO DO LIST:</p>
                    <ul id="myList">
                    </ul>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I took the javascript portion, put it in its own file, and now the extension works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var text = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    node.innerHTML = textnode;
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
  });
};
```